# Error: Failed to refresh token in Azure AD APPS for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, token, azureadapps

I am creating an Azure AD  Single tenant Application using  asp.net to Provisioning SharePoint site collections. I am able to create site collections as the APP is giving full rights on SharePoint in Azure portal. But when i am trying to access the  specific site collection (https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletestsite/), getting the Error

```
 Failed to refresh token
```

Below is the code i am using to get the access token  from the azure and  creating the SharePoint context.

```
public ClientContext GetSharePointContext(string SiteUrl)
{
    ClientContext spContext = null;
    try
    {

        Task<string> result = Task.Run<string>(async () => await GetAccessToken(SiteUrl));
        result.Wait();
        if (result != null)
            spContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(SiteUrl, result.Result);

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return spContext;
}

public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string siteurl)
{
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult=null;
    try
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
        authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(siteurl, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {

        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

First  i am passing the `https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/` url and getting the access token and creating the SharePoint context and creating the site collection,which is working fine. Now again i am passing the site collection url `https://tenenat.sharepoint.com/sites/sampletestsite/`  and getting the   **Failed to refresh token**  Error. Can anyone help me on  this.

Answer (score 0):

AcquireTokenSilentAsync try to get token silently but may fail after 90 days of login, in that case you need to call AcquireTokenAsync 
Refer below code

```
try
{
   authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_resource, _clientId).Result;
}
  catch (AggregateException exception) when (exception.InnerException is AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
{
  authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resource,
  _clientId, new Uri(_returnUri), _platformParameter).Result;
}
```